TV show from possibly 90's to early 2000's where playhouse turned into a bigger room and gave people what they wished for
I know this may sound a little weird but I remember when I was younger watching a show on TV, or could have possibly been a movie, where there are these children who go into their outdoor playhouse but it brings them to some kind of room that grants what they want. I remember where this girl gets a Barbie collection she wanted, but also remember that if they did something wrong, there was a grey or possibly metallic silver wall that had faces coming out of it that would absorb them.
At the end I believe there were adults coming back from the the playhouse but not entirely sure. I believe one of the songs from the show at the time that was playing in it was Your Woman by White Town but can't recall the name of the show.

Sounds like the Friday the 13th: The Series ep The Playhouse (Season 2, Episode 12) from 1989.

Micki, Ryan and Jack travel to a small town where the disappearance of several children is linked to a mysterious toy playhouse.

The playhouse contains a bigger room on the inside. Two kids lure other kids into it by promising them they can get whatever they want, and it absorbs them into its gray walls, where their heads and hands stick out of it. There's very little chance it featured Your Woman though, which came out 8 years later. Here's the promo:



